# How to delete the following row of a conditional row in a R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

I am still learning how NOT to use for loops in R. 
I can't figure out how to combine a condition and an iteration like procedure...
In a large dataframe I need to eliminate all rows for r = 0, but I also need to eliminate the row that follows this row.

For example in the Df dataframe i need to get rid of rows 4,5,8 and 9.

```
Df
    x r
1  12 1
2  15 1
3  36 1 
4   4 0 
5  89 1
6   6 1
7  52 1
8   3 0
9  67 1
10 85 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute the indexes of the 0 rows and then remove those as well as each index plus 1.

```
ix <- which(Df$r == 0)
Df[-c(ix, ix + 1), ]
```

giving:

```
    x r
1  12 1
2  15 1
3  36 1
6   6 1
7  52 1
10 85 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
r1 = Df$r != 0 
r2 = c(TRUE, r1[1:(length(r1) - 1)])
Df = Df[r1 & r2,]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option to use the `filter` and `lag` function from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

DF2 <- DF %>% filter(!(r == 0 | lag(r, default = 1) == 0))
DF2
#    x r
# 1 12 1
# 2 15 1
# 3 36 1
# 4  6 1
# 5 52 1
# 6 85 1
```